# Comparison of Vaticanus and Siniaticus in an interlineary

Tags: greek, textual-criticism, manuscript

This is my problem: I would like to be able to compare the two most referred-to texts (which most modern versions are based on); but I cannot find a way to do it. I do not read Greek - though I am learning little-by-little. I do not understand why this is not available in 2020.

I can get the Siniaticus in Logos. I know there are facsimile editions of that as well. I know that it is available online.

It seems to me that thousands of students of the Scriptures would appreciate being able to compare these two manuscripts in particular.

My surprise and frustration is based on this late date, what would prevent the Vaticanus being made available in a user-friendly version? It is 2020!

Can anyone correct me with information as to how I can obtain this kind of interlinear? If it doesn't exist, I would like to hear from those in-the-know, why they think that is.

I know I can look at critical texts. I don't think that is good enough. When I read some Bibles they say, "the oldest and most reliable ..." But, as you know, they do not include a designation for א, A, B, etc.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Their main differences seem to be in [Joshua](http://www.greekdoc.com/polyglot/joshua01.html) and [Judges](http://www.greekdoc.com/polyglot/judges01.html).

Comment: Elizabeth - the best way to compare all the MSS, including Vaticanus and Sinaiticus is to use UBS4 or UBS5 which lists all the variations - the modern text of the NT is based on much more than just these two and regularly differs from them.

Comment: Sinaiticus and Vaticanus are important but not the only ones.  If I want to know what either says I simply consult UBS5 or NA28 to find what almost any of the MSS text is.  The problem is, if such a document as you describe were created, the market would not support it because the information already exists in a more accessible place.

Answer (score 1):

I really think you are better off going with a modern apparatus instead of trying to build one out of two manuscripts, but in terms of NT you can download Vaticanus online for free here: http://www.truebiblecode.com/codexvaticanus.html

And you can download Sinaiticus online for free here:
https://codexsinaiticus.org/en/

Or from logos:
https://www.logos.com/product/35581/codex-sinaiticus

And there is a community effort to turn Vaticanus into a personal book, although I'm not sure of the status. See https://community.logos.com/forums/t/177881.aspx